# How to change the Permission Handler old version to the new version

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, kotlin, visual-studio-code

i have the old permission handler code, but i'm using the latest version of `pubspec.yaml` . how to change the code below with the latest version?? is there someone who can help me

```
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      PermissionStatus permissionStorage = await PermissionHandler().checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.storage);
      if (permissionStorage != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> permissionStatus = await PermissionHandler().requestPermission([PermissionGroup.storage]);
        permissionStorage = permissionStatus[PermissionGroup.storage] ?? PermissionStatus.unknow;

        if (permissionStatus != PermissionStatus.granted) {
          print('no storage permission to save image');
          return;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Await request().isGranted. It will ask for permission if it's not granted.

```dart
if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
  // permission granted
}
else{
print('no storage permission to save image');
          
}
```